# how can i change dynamically with php the width of a html div?

Tags: php, html, css

in my website i have FAQ  page which the users can add questions and images

```
<div class="FAQ container">
<div class="content">text text text</div>
<div class="pic"><img></div>
 </div>
```

if the user adds only text to the question then div  .class should be 100% width
if the user adds text and img the 2 divs should be 50% each,
next to each other,
how can i do it?

Comment: This can be done in many ways. For one there would be no need to print the pic (album) div if there are no images.

Comment: You've mentioned the solution yourself `if .... elseif ...` So I don't see where's the problem ?

Comment: Most likely it is better to do this in JS, not in PHP. In php you only could do some hard coded styling which is ugly as hell and interferes with the class usage you do. So make a JS routine instead that check if there are any images present right when the page has loaded and resizes the divs as required if so.

Comment: Do you need the HTML markup like that? You could simplify it and simply not print the image: [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdah/)

Comment: @arkascha while you could use JavaScript to solve this, there is nothing bad about addressing this with PHP and more than likely would be the preferred solution by most if you're already dynamically generating the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using a database like MySQL. I'm also going to assume that your your database query returns the following fields *question*, *answer* and _image_path_.

*PHP*

```php
 $faq_html = '<div class="faq %s"><div class="content">Q: %s<br>A: %s</div>%s</div>';
 while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) :
      $container_class = 'no-image';
      $faq_img_html = '';
      if ( ! empty( $row->image_path ) ) :
           $container_class = 'has-image';
           $faq_img_html = sprintf( '<div class="pic"><img src="%s" /></div>', $row->image_path );
      endif;
      $faqs .= sprintf( $faq_html, $container_class, $row->question, $row->answer,  $faq_img_html );
 endwhile;

 echo '<div class="faqs-container">' . $faqs . '</div>';
```

The output would either have a class of `.no-image` or `.has-image` on a DIV wrapper for each individual FAQ.

*HTML*

```
 <div class="faq no-image">
      <div class="content">
           Q: text text text? <br>
           A: text text text
      </div>
 </div>

<div class="faq has-image">
      <div class="content">
           Q: text text text? <br>
           A: text text text
      </div>
      <div class="pic"><img src="your-img.jpg" /></div>
 </div>
```

Once you have that just sprinkle in a little CSS.

```css
 .no-image .content { width: 100%; }
 .has-image .content,
 .has-image .pic { width: 50%; }
```

Comment: \thank you for your help
\ but i get an error "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object "

Comment: My example uses PHPs `MySQLi`.  Your implementation might be different.  The method is `fetch_object()`.

Comment: i work on the css/html of this project, i know less about php, so here is the php code that i think relates with the div-dynamically width issue,so if there isnt image in the answers reservoir---> than div width = 100% - ,if there is image than --->div width = 50/50

Comment: <?php foreach($articles as $article) :?>                                           
    <div class="parent  ques_close"><?php echo $article->getTitle(); ?></div>
    <div class="child">
    <?php echo $article->getContent(); ?>
    <?php if ($article->getImagePath()) :?>
    <div class="faq_image"><img alt="faq image" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$article->getImagePath(); ?>" /></div> 
    <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, the text-Div is always filled and the Image-Div only sometimes, right?
For this situation I would suggest, that you try this CSS (unchecked):

```
.pic{
 max-width: 50%;
 float: right;
}

.FAQcontainer{ /* you can not have space in class names */
  clear: both;
}
```

This way the Image-Div will be shown on the right side. If it does not contain an image, then it will be very small. If it conatins an image, it will not be wider than 50% of the FAQcontainer-Div.

Please be aware that some older browsers do not understand 'max-width'. And if the image is wider than this 50%, it will take it place and "destroy" the layout.

A more reliable solution would be to generate these DIVs dynamically by a server-side Script which prints out the Image-Div only if needed. The script could also take care of the different images sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this - with PHP or JavaScript:

**PHP**

You could apply different classes depending on whether their is a image or not, and then style them differently. If each answer/image set is stored as an array, you can check to see if an image is applied then echo a class if the image is not empty.

**JavaScript**

This would be the method I would be inclined to use. With JavaScript, check to see if an image is their, then change the styles appropriately. However, make sure there is an appropriate CSS only fallback for browsers with JS disabled (e.g. have image above text for those users).

Comment: `their` should be `there`